# Codeigniter XML-RPC Sample code issue

Tags: codeigniter, xml-rpc

Trying to run Codeigniter User Guide XML RPC Sample Code.

This is the code

xmlrpc_client.php

```
<?php

 class Xmlrpc_client extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $server_url = site_url('xmlrpc_server');

    $this->load->library('xmlrpc');

    $this->xmlrpc->server($server_url, 80);
    $this->xmlrpc->method('Greetings');

    $request = array('How is it going?');
    $this->xmlrpc->request($request);

    if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
    {
        echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->xmlrpc->display_response());
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}}?>
```

xmlrpc_server.php

```
<?php

 class Xmlrpc_server extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
    $this->load->library('xmlrpc');
    $this->load->library('xmlrpcs');

    $config['functions']['Greetings'] = array('function' => 'Xmlrpc_server.process');

    $this->xmlrpcs->initialize($config);
    $this->xmlrpcs->serve();
}


function process($request)
{
    $parameters = $request->output_parameters();

    $response = array(
                        array(
                                'you_said'  => $parameters['0'],
                                'i_respond' => 'Not bad at all.'),
                        'struct');

    return $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);
}}?>
```

After this, i ran the url like this.

**remoteserver's ip/xmlrpc_client**

(i deleted my index.php using .htaccess, dont need to type it)

the result is like this,

**Did not receive a '200 OK' response from remote server. (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)**

If i run the server code, 
**remoteserver's ip/xmlrpc_server** 
it says like this.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Which means,

$this->xmlrpc->send_request()

this request have been failed

and echoed

echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();

Any idea what is the problem is?

Oh, i have another question.

Do i have to install xmlrpc php extension before i use this codeigniter xmlrpc class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! the problem was the remote sever's firewall.

Comment: I am hosting both server and client on localhost and my firewall is disabled still not working!